# How to link the tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have 3 tables in my mysql database: `student, progress and subject`. When I try to select data:

```
SELECT progress.id, progress.mark, subject.pname FROM progress, subject WHERE   progress.id_student = 1;
```

I get the following table:

```
id  mark  pname
1   5     Math
1   5     Physics
```

Table progress I only have one entry:

```
id  mark   id_student   id_subject
1   5      1            1
```

How can I get student progress by `student_id`?

```
CREATE DATABASE students;
USE students;
CREATE TABLE student (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
address varchar(60) NOT NULL,
byear int NOT NULL,
eyear int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE subject (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pname varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE progress (
id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
mark int NOT NULL,
id_student int NOT NULL,
id_subject int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES student (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES subject (id)
);
```

Comment: you already get the output.So what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT progress.id, progress.mark, subject.pname 
FROM progress LEFT OUTER JOIN subject ON (progress.id_subject= subject.id)
WHERE   progress.id_student = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT progress.id, progress.mark, subject.pname 
FROM progress, subject
WHERE progress.id_student = 1 AND progress.id_subject = subject.id;
```